# i have a problem to open action sheet in ionic 5

Tags: ionic4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWuxj.png)i have a problem to open action sheet in ionic 5.
I have tried so many times but the result is 0. please suggest me some good suggestion
regards: najam khan[here is my code[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ztr9.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please do not share code or the expected output as pictures.

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend generating the buttons, here is an example

```
let botonesSelecion = [];
itemSeleccion.ListaSeleccion.forEach(dato => {
  botonesSelecion.push({
    text: dato.OpcionSeleccion,
    //icon: 'radio-button-on-outline',
    handler: () => {
      itemSeleccion.OpcionSeleccion = dato.OpcionSeleccion;
    }
  });
});

const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
  header: itemSeleccion.Descripcion,
  cssClass: 'fondo-lista-desplegable',
  buttons: botonesSelecion
});
await actionSheet.present();
```